# Is it possible to use client side smtp?

Tags: meteor

Real world problem: When meteor app lost connection with a self deployed meteor server,
it would be a nice solution to send email automatically from client side with the data,
what is not refreshing to other clients while server is offline...
Is it possible? I mean haven't seen any

```
if (Meteor.isClient) { MAIL_URL = 'smtp://....
sendMessage(this.userId, toId, msg);
```

likes... however client could use google smtp for example

Comment: It's not possible to send emails via JS.

Comment: Well, then what is haraka.js?

Comment: "send email automatically from client side with the data" - Haraka is server-side, not client-side.

Comment: Of course, but it's JS :) So the nearest possible solution is to install another Node on each client and program something like this...: https://gist.github.com/devongovett/1326727

Answer (score 0):

A secondary server might be wiser than email. [There *is* a package](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-cluster) for clustering Meteor servers.

Comment: Agree, but I don't know why, it's always hard to convince the clients to buy another server for their own good, and as we know, without money there's no responsibility :'(

Comment: @user3018234 Then you should explain to them that when a server is down, it can't serve anything. If they can't afford one, then they should face the risk of downtime.